# I am trying to create a textview like HTML List item using array list of spannable. How to animate each spannable?

Tags: android, android-animation, textview

I have taken a utlity called BulletListBuilder to build a textview like HTML List item. BulletListBuilder takes List as argument and convert each string to Bulletspan so that it will display like bullet list.

Animate each span means The appearance of entire list will random for e.g if bullet list is of five line. Then first line animation is like fade in, second line animation is slide up, third line animation is slide right like so on.When user see this screen, list item will appear one by one and that too with different animation.

How to do this in below code ?

```
 public class BulletListBuilder {

        private static final String SPACE = " ";
        private static final String BULLET_SYMBOL = "&#8226";
        private static final String EOL = System.getProperty("line.separator");
        private static final String TAB = "\t";
        private  Context context;
        public BulletListBuilder(Context context) {
        this.context = context;
        }

        public  CharSequence getBulletList(String header, List<String> items, String bullet) {

            List<Spanned> spanned = new ArrayList<>(items.size());
            for (String line : items) {
                if (!line.trim().isEmpty()) {
                    Spanned spannedLine = Html.fromHtml(line.trim());
                    spanned.add(spannedLine);
                }
            }

            SpannableStringBuilder sb = new SpannableStringBuilder();

            for (int i = 0; i < spanned.size(); i++) {
                CharSequence line = spanned.get(i) + (i < spanned.size() - 1 ? "\n" : "");
                Spannable spannable = new SpannableString(line);

                //for colour
                spannable.setSpan(new ForegroundColorSpan(context.getResources()
                        .getColor(R.color.colorAccent)), 0, 2, 0);

                //size increase
                spannable.setSpan(new RelativeSizeSpan(1.5f), 0, 3, 0);

                //bold
                spannable.setSpan(new StyleSpan(Typeface.BOLD), spannable.length()-3,
                        spannable.length()-1, 0);

                spannable.setSpan(new MyClickableSpan(spannable.toString()),
                        3,
                        spannable.length()-4, 0);


                spannable.setSpan(new BulletSpan(60), 0, spannable.length(),
                        Spanned.SPAN_USER);
                sb.append(spannable);


            }

            return sb;
        }
    }
```

here is my Activity code

```
 TextView list = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.list);

        List<String> lines = new ArrayList<>();
        lines.add("First line");
        lines.add("Second line");
        lines.add("Really long third line that will wrap and indent properly.");
        lines.add("FOurth");
        lines.add("Really long third line that will wrap and indent properly.");


        //CharSequence bulletedList = BulletListUtil.makeBulletList(lines,30);
        list.setText(new BulletListBuilder(getContext()).getBulletList("Hero",lines,""));
```

Comment: Please edit your question and explain, **in detail**, what it mean to animate a bullet line. What **exactly** are you expecting to change about that line as part of this animation?

Comment: updated the question pls have a look

Comment: You did not explain what it means to animate a bullet line.

Comment: Please check the question

Comment: I sincerely doubt that what you want is possible with a single `TextView`. Consider using one `TextView` per line (and animating the views, not the text), using `WebView` (and using CSS animations), or rendering this text yourself to a `Canvas`.

Comment: please read post  mentioned in the link i m sure u will not doubt  i need syntax which is not avaivable ins this post To do it but i believe its possible to animate the span     http://flavienlaurent.com/blog/2014/01/31/spans/

Comment: You can animate effects on the text itself, such as changing the color. However, I sincerely doubt that you can *move* the text, which is part of what you are seeking.

Comment: Since textview consist of five different spannable object, any animation to made on textview will impact all spannable object where as i want to animate single span. Spannable interface has a method called setspan which takes object as argument but animation object is not able to set it.

Comment: "any animation to made on textview will impact all spannable object where as i want to animate single span" -- which is why I suggested having five `TextView` widgets (one per line), and you animate the widgets. Or, use a `WebView`. Or, use a `Canvas`.

Comment: its a random list. five text view wont help much (its kindda work around) if i go for webview i cannot animate each list item as css in smaller version of android wont work perfectly.

Comment: "five text view wont help much" -- then create N `TextView` widgets, where N is the size of your list. Or use a `RecyclerView` as the overall container, with `TextView` widgets for the rows, and use `RecyclerView`'s item animations to handle sliding lines around as you move them with the `RecyclerView` data model.